# How to traverse a list of objects in Node.js

Tags: node.js, for-loop

With the following code I get the error underneath:

```
for (event of events) {
    var newEvent = new Event(event);
    newEvent.save();
}
```

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in 0

I tried to the following code, but the problem persists:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= events.length; i ++ ) {
    var newEvent = new Event(i);
    newEvent.save();
}
```

EDIT:

With the new code I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in 1

I've installed Robomongo to see if the documents have been added and it seems the id of the document has been added and nothing more.

Comment: What is `events`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first loop you can use:

```
for (event in events) {
var newEvent = new Event(event);
newEvent.save();
}
```

in the second loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= events.length; i ++ ) {
var newEvent = new Event(events[i]);
newEvent.save();
```

}